# помогите найти ошибку в моей программе

Tags: python, массивы

> Опишите на русском языке или одном из языков программирования алгоритм подсчета максимального количества подряд идущих четных элементов в целочисленном массиве длины 30.

помогите найти ошибку, я не понимаю почему у меня выдает ошибку list index out of range на 5 строке

```
a = []
k = 0 
for i in range(1,31):
    a.append(int(input()))
    if a[i] % 2 == 0:
        p = p + 1
    else:
        p = 0
    if p > k :
        k = p
print(k)
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь пожалуйста отладчиком, такие вопросы в будущем отпадут сами собой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Индексы массивов начинаются с 0, а цикл вы начинаете с 1. Инструкция `a.append(int(input()))` записывает число в элемент `a[0]`, но в следующей строке вы пытаетесь обратиться к несуществующему элементу `a[1]`.

Comment: так же стоит помнить, что и последнее число тоже нужно уменьшить на 1: `range(0, 30)`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @ВаняКарбушев [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).